# Inverse reference lookup

Tags: java, xtext, emf, xtend

For some reasons my `JvmModelInferrer` *needs* to search for all elements of a special type which fulfill a criterion. These elements are necessary to infer the model completely. But all these elements can be spread over all source code files of the project. More precise: There is an element which introduces a class and several elements which modify this class. The grammar for this looks like this (simplified to a minimum depth):

```
DeltaAction:
    AddsUnit | ModifiesUnit | RemovesUnit;

AddsUnit:
    {AddsUnit} 'adds' '{' unit=JavaCompilationUnit? '}';

JavaCompilationUnit:
    ('package' name=QualifiedName EOL)?
    importSection=XImportSection?
    // ...
    typeDeclarations=ClassOrInterface;

ClassOrInterface:
    ClassDeclaration /* | ... */;

ClassDeclaration:
    'class' name=QualifiedName
    // ...
    ;

ModifiesUnit:
    'modifies' unit=[ClassOrInterface|QualifiedName] '{'
    // ...
    '}';
```

If I now infer the jvm model for a class `pkg.A`, I need to find all `ModifiesUnit` units which reference `pkg.A` to generate this class.

This is more or less the question: How can I find all elements referencing `pkg.A`? I found a soultion, but I think it is very inperformant and maybe there is any API which does i for me much more efficient.

class DeltaJJvmModelInferrer extends AbstractModelInferrer {

```
@Inject ResourceDescriptionsProvider descsProvider
@Inject ResourceSet set
@Inject IQualifiedNameProvider qnameProvider

def dispatch void infer(DeltaJUnit unit, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
    descsProvider.createResourceDescriptions.allResourceDescriptions.forEach [ rd |
            val res = set.getResource(rd.URI, true)
            res.unload
            res.load(null)
            EcoreUtil2.resolveAll(res)
        ]
        try {
            set.allContents.filter(typeof(ModifiesUnit)).filter [ mu |
                qnameProvider.getFullyQualifiedName(mu.unit).equals(qnameProvider.getFullyQualifiedName(cd))
            ].forEach [ mu |
                // Do the stuff I need to do!
            ]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what avout asking the index for all ModifiesUnit with the wanted name and then have a look?

Comment: and have a look at the reference descriptions in the index

Comment: I haven't used the index yet. I will have a look at it tomorrow. Is there any documentation about its usage?

Comment: descsProvider.createResourceDescriptions is the index - an no there is no docs on that - but you can ask a iresourcedescription for information

Comment: the other possibility is to store the information directly in the index (modify DefaultResourceDEscriptionStrategy and store the information in the user data map) - use the nodemodelutils to retrieve the information since the model is not linked then)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Christian Dietrich! Your idea works very good.

My solution for a fast, specialised reverse reference lookup looks like this:

1. I extended the `XbaseResourceDescriptionStrategy` to add custom data to the index. The custom data is a key/value pair which has `'ModifiesUnit'` as key and the qualified name of the referenced class (`qnp.getFullyQualifiedName(mu.unit)`) as value:

   ```
   class DeltaJResourceDescriptionStrategy extends XbaseResourceDescriptionStrategy {

       public static val TYPE = 'ModifiesUnit'

       override def createEObjectDescriptions(EObject eObject, IAcceptor<IEObjectDescription> acceptor) {
           var custom = true
           try {
               if (eObject instanceof ModifiesUnit) {
                   if (!eObject.eIsProxy) {
                       val qname = qnp.getFullyQualifiedName(eObject.unit)
                       acceptor.accept(EObjectDescription.create(qname, eObject, eObject.createModifiesUnitUserData))
                   }
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               custom = false
           }
           super.createEObjectDescriptions(eObject, acceptor) && custom
       }

       def createModifiesUnitUserData(ModifiesUnit mu) {
           val map = newHashMap
           map.put(TYPE, qualifiedNameProvider.getFullyQualifiedName(mu.unit).toString)
           map
       }
   }
   ```
2. I created an index wrapper class which currently only provides a method which returns a list of all `ModifiesUnit`s which modify a given class. It uses the qualified name to identify the modifies units I want to have:

   ```
   class DeltaJIndex {

       @Inject extension ResourceDescriptionsProvider
       @Inject extension QualifiedNameProvider
       @Inject extension ResourceSet

       def getAllResourceDescriptions() {
           createResourceDescriptions.allResourceDescriptions
       }

       def getAllModifyUnitsOf(ClassOrInterface ci) {
           val Set<ModifiesUnit> units = newHashSet
           val Set<Resource> resources = newHashSet
           val ciQn = qnProvider.getFullyQualifiedName(ci).toString

           rdProvider.getResourceDescriptions(ci.eResource).allResourceDescriptions.forEach [ list |
               list.exportedObjects.forEach [ object |
                   if (object.userDataKeys.contains(TYPE) && object.getUserData(TYPE) == ciQn) {
                       val res = set.getResource(object.EObjectURI, true)
                       if (!resources.contains(res)) {
                           res.unload
                           res.load(null)
                           resources.add(res)
                       }
                       units.add(res.getEObject(object.EObjectURI.fragment) as ModifiesUnit)
                   }
               ]
           ]
           units
       }
   }
   ```

   The only problem is, that I have to unload every resource and load it again. Otherwise the content of any resource is not in the same state if they were edited since the last Eclipse start-up.
3. Accessing all `ModifiesUnit`s which modify a certain class is now that simple: `val modifiesUnits = index.allModifyUnitsForCi(cd)`.

Comment: Mh, I have a new problem ... The loaded resources will not sync with changes I perform to the `ModfifiesUnit`s ... The list contains all resources with the state they had directly after Eclipse was started.

Comment: what do you mean by "The loaded resources"

Comment: btw you should use org.eclipse.xtext.resource.impl.ResourceDescriptionsProvider.getResourceDescriptions(Resource)

Comment: Ok, I now use your provided method. My problem now is the following:

Comment: I have fixed my problems. Have a look in my answer, I have updted it.